# How to update cart qty using ajax Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cart, ajax, shopping-cart

**How to update cart qty using ajax magento 2**

I want to change qty on cart page. 
I don't want to use the update button. It should be update automatically without reloading the page.

Answer (score 9):

**Reload totals cart after ajax change quantity** 
1. Step

In your custom them create ( Magento_Theme/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml )

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="cart.ajax.qty.update"  template="Magento_Theme::js.phtml" after="-"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

2.Step

creat js.phtml file ( Magento_Theme/templates/js.phtml )

```
<script>
require ([
        'jquery',
    ],
    function ($) {
       $(window).on("load", function () {
            require([
                'custom'
            ]);
        });
    });
```

3. Step
create custom.js file in theme web folder ( Namespace/Yourtheme/web/js/custom.js )

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
     ], function ($, getTotalsAction, customerData) {

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'input[name$="[qty]"]', function(){
        var form = $('form#form-validate');
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            showLoader: true,
            success: function (res) {
                var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
                var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");
                var sections = ['cart'];

                $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);

                // The mini cart reloading
                customerData.reload(sections, true);

                // The totals summary block reloading
                var deferred = $.Deferred();
                getTotalsAction([], deferred);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                console.log(err.Message);
            }
        });
       });
      });
    });
```

4.Step  ( map your js file )

Create requirejs-config.js on your theme root ( Namespace/yourtheme/requirejs-config.js)

```
var config = {
   map: {
    '*': {
        custom:'js/custom'
    }
  }
};
```

Now the qty update work using ajax 
If have any issue ask in comment.

Comment: Hello Surendra Kumar Ahir. Please elaborate the answer. We are trying to achieve this.

Comment: Hello, I am trying to implement you method on my Magento 2.2 store but having some difficulties. It would be great if you can take a look at this thread: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253404/magento-2-update-cart-automatically-on-carty-quantity-update-gives-error-mismat?noredirect=1#comment357163_253404

Comment: Hi, I followed each step and It works fine but sometimes I get the error in console “customer-data.js:89 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘sectionLoadUrl’ of undefined” and due to the error totals not loading.
When I remove this js ‘Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals’ then It works fine.

Anyone help me to resolve the error? Thank You

Comment: after ajax qty update how to get cart subtotal I tried with totals.totals()['subtotal'] but it takes old subtotal

Comment: Hi - how do I apply this on the whole website?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your approach, it is working for me if i enter the quantity in quantity textfield. But it doesn't work if i use increment/decrement signs to update the quanity. Can you please guide me how can do this.

```
$('.qty-down-fixed-onclick-page-cart, .qty-up-fixed-onclick-page-cart').on('click',  ajaxQuantityUpdate);
```

Above code works but only once. After ajax call it stops working. 
Secondly my product image breaks after ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the current solution is good although I had the same problem, here's how I solved it:

1. Edit this file Magento_Checkout/templates/cart/form.phtml in your own theme. Remove the following part:

   ```
   <script>
   require([
   'jquery',
   'mage/mage'
   ], function ($) {
   'use strict';       
   $(".qty-down-fixed-onclick-page-cart").click(function() {
       var number_click = parseInt($(this).closest('div.qty').find('.input-text.qty').attr('data-qty'));
       var val_input = $(this).closest('div.qty').find('.input-text.qty').val();
       val_input = parseInt(val_input);
       if(val_input <= number_click){
           val_input = number_click;
       }
       else{
           val_input = val_input - number_click;
       }
       $(this).closest('div.qty').find('.input-text.qty').val(val_input);
       return false;
   });
   $(".qty-up-fixed-onclick-page-cart").click(function() {
       var number_click_2 = parseInt($(this).closest('div.qty').find('.input-text.qty').attr('data-qty'));
       var val_input = $(this).closest('div.qty').find('.input-text.qty').val();
       val_input = parseInt(val_input);
       val_input = val_input + number_click_2;
       $(this).closest('div.qty').find('.input-text.qty').val(val_input);
       return false;
   });
   });
   </script>
   ```
2. Edit the custom.js file form the current solution to:

   ```
   define(['jquery','Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
   'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
   'mage/mage'
   ], function ($, getTotalsAction, customerData) {
   'use strict';
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).on(
           'input',
           'input[name$="[qty]"]',
           function(){
               reloadCart();
       });
       $(document).on(
           'click',
           '.qty-down-fixed-onclick-page-cart',
           function(){
           var number_click = parseInt($(this).closest('div.qty').find('.input-text.qty').attr('data-qty'));
           var val_input = $(this).closest('div.qty').find('.input-text.qty').val();
           var current_val = val_input;
           val_input = parseInt(val_input);
           if(val_input <= number_click){
               val_input = number_click;
           }
           else{
               val_input = val_input - number_click;
           }
           $(this).closest('div.qty').find('.input-text.qty').val(val_input);
           if (current_val > 1)
           {
               reloadCart();
           }
           return false;
       }
       );
       $(document).on(
           'click',
           '.qty-up-fixed-onclick-page-cart',
           function(){
               var number_click_2 = parseInt($(this).closest('div.qty').find('.input-text.qty').attr('data-qty'));
               var val_input = $(this).closest('div.qty').find('.input-text.qty').val();
               val_input = parseInt(val_input);
               val_input = val_input + number_click_2;
               $(this).closest('div.qty').find('.input-text.qty').val(val_input);
               reloadCart();
               return false;
           }
       );
   });

   function reloadCart() {
       var form = $('form#form-validate');
       $.ajax({
           url: form.attr('action'),
           data: form.serialize(),
           showLoader: true,
           success: function (res) {
               var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
               var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");
               var sections = ['cart'];
               $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);

               // The mini cart reloading
               customerData.reload(sections, true);

               // The totals summary block reloading
               var deferred = $.Deferred();
               getTotalsAction([], deferred);
           },
           error: function (xhr, status, error) {
               var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
               console.log(err.Message);
           }
       });
   }
   });
   ```

This way you'll get:

1. On input "event" and not "change". This prevents an additional click
   outside the quantity box when you manually enter a quantity.
2. On every qty increment or decrement the cart will reload on click of the arrows unless quantity is 1 on the arrow down click.

Comment: How can i get cartSubtotal in this custom.js