# Magento 2 Update cart automatically on carty quantity update gives error "Mismatched anonymous define() module"

Tags: magento2.2, cart, javascript, ajax

I have done everything mentioned in this [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235040/how-to-update-cart-qty-using-ajax-magento-2), however, it gives me an error in console:

```
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ($, getTotalsAction, customerData) {

$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('change', 'input[name$="[qty]"]', function(){
    var form = $('form#form-validate');
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        showLoader: true,
        success: function (res) {
            var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(res);
            var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#form-validate");
            var sections = ['cart'];

            $("#form-validate").replaceWith(result);

            // The mini cart reloading
            customerData.reload(sections, true);

            // The totals summary block reloading
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            getTotalsAction([], deferred);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            console.log(err.Message);
        }
    });
   });
  });
}
```

No idea how to solve this...

**UPDATE:**

I am not using a custom module, all the code is being added to the custom theme directory.

Comment: Are you creating custom js for your module?

Comment: No, I am not. The reference material never mentioned a post. All the changes are made in the custom theme.

Comment: try require instead of define

Comment: If you take a look a the `js.phtml` file, there is a `require` already added above the whole js document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow steps given below to resolve the issue.

**step 1)** Please move the **custom.js** file

To

***app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Theme/web/js***

**step 2)** Update your **requirejs-config.js** as given below

```
var config = {
   map: {
    '*': {
        custom:'Magento_Theme/js/custom'
    }
  }
};
```

**step 3)** Please update **js.phtml** located under **/app/design/frontend/Vendor/customtheme/Magento_Theme/templates/**

File : **js.phtml**

```
<script>
require ([
        'jquery',
    ],
    function ($) {
       $(window).on("load", function () {
            require([
                'custom'
            ]);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Please remove static content (sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*) and flush cache**

Comment: It actually worked... what is the reason why it didn't work the other way?

Comment: The reason is custom.js file location was not correct. that's why it was not working properly.

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't work for me