# How to update item total, sub total, and cart total without reload page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I create a custom block to display the cart total in magento 2. But I want to update the total and quantity in the right block when a user plus or minus product in the left block.

Please help me how to do that with knockout JS. My design as below.

Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Hey You can use ajax request for this i mean whenever you update Qty or updation in product you can call the updation  function which will update your price as well.

Comment: Hi Shubham Khandelwal, I am using ajax follow this guide https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235040/how-to-update-cart-qty-using-ajax-magento-2 However, the ajax update only order total and subtotal. It cannot update the number items and total of item. After ajax update the tax conent is loss. Could you help me the solution? and I want to ask how to update block with ajax? I wrote a file custom-summary.phtml to display the right sidebar. How to reload only it with ajax?