# Total Cart Price in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Sorry for the beginner question and seriously needed help but currently I am using the checkout module to get the total cart price and display it in my header however the problem is that when I add something to the cart the total cart price is not updated in the header however when I am in the checkout page it suddenly updated. Is their any way I can make the total cart price update real time even though I am not in the checkout page ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep but you need to use Ajax.

You can watch this :

[How to update cart qty using ajax Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/235040/how-to-update-cart-qty-using-ajax-magento-2)

And adapt it to update the price

Comment: sir, I am having a hard time following it, because I not too familiar in magento 2 and just got recently worked on it

Comment: I have a minicart.phtml and I want to update the total cart price their

Comment: Maybe look here (easy way) : https://webkul.com/blog/update-mini-cart-magento2/

Comment: Or here (better if you want to learn how magento work) : https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-update-cart-quantity-in-magento-2-via-ajax.html

Comment: I read the links however still don't know really where to start but maybe we can connect so that I can show you the code